# How to get Max Values of a Multidimensional Array for 30 Days

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, multidimensional-array, chart.js

I am creating a historical Graph using ChartJS. And I need to Filter the array Values 30 Days Ago

I have an array with the values below:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 4/1/2019 4:00:00 PM - 5:00:00 PM
        [value_raw] => 100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 4/1/2019 3:00:00 PM - 4:00:00 PM
        [value_raw] => 101
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 4/1/2019 2:00:00 PM - 3:00:00 PM
        [value_raw] => 99
    )
```

The Array has large content and contains up to more than 5 months value of every hour every day

This is my current php code as of now for the labels in the ChartJS Script:

LABELS CODE:

```
labels: [
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i<=30; $i++)
        {
         $label = date('n/d/Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime(date('n/d/Y'))));
         echo '"'.$label.'",';
        }
    ?>
],
```

Result:

```
4/01/2019, 3/31/2019, 3/30/2019, 3/29/2019
```

However I'am having hard time on how am I going to get the equivalent MAX Value per day in parallel to/matching my Labels Code.

DATA CODE:

```
data: [
    <?php
    foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
        for($i=0; $i<=30; $i++)
        {
            $label = date('n/d/Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime(date('n/d/Y'))));

             if ($label == changeFormat($value[datetime]))
             {
                     echo $value['value_raw'].',';
             }
        }
    }
    ?>
],
```

My Expected Result should be the MAX Value of the Day of the Past 30 Days :

Example:

```
DATE        VALUE
4/01/2019   99
3/31/2019   101
3/30/2019   100
3/29/2019   95
```

Result:

```
99, 101, 100, 95
```

Comment: if using mysql then `SELECT MAX(value_raw), DATE(mydate) DateOnly FROM a_table where mydate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
 GROUP BY DateOnly;` Should to be the trick to go

Comment: @RahulMeshram yes, thts what needed

Comment: Hi everyone, unfortunately I'am not using MySQL in here, I get the array using json via API

Comment: @c18online have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question was about sorting multi-dimesional array based on the key, try this

```
// remove dates older than 30 days
function remove30DayBeforeDates($a) {
    $pieces = explode(' ', $a['datetime']);
    return strtotime($pieces[0]) > strtotime('-30 days');
}
// remove dates older than 30 days

$array = array(
    array(
        'datetime' => '3/29/2019 4:00:00 PM - 5:00:00 PM',
        'value_raw' => 95
    ), array(
        'datetime' => '4/01/2019 3:00:00 PM - 4:00:00 PM',
        'value_raw' => 99
    ), array(
        'datetime' => '3/31/2019 2:00:00 PM - 3:00:00 PM',
        'value_raw' => 101
    ), array(
        'datetime' => '2/10/2019 2:00:00 PM - 3:00:00 PM',
        'value_raw' => 112
    ), array(
        'datetime' => '3/30/2019 2:00:00 PM - 3:00:00 PM',
        'value_raw' => 100
        ));

$array = array_filter($array, "remove30DayBeforeDates");

// sort array based on the date

function check($a, $b) {
    $pieces1 = explode(' ', $a['datetime']);
    $pieces2 = explode(' ', $b['datetime']);
    return strtotime($pieces2[0]) <=> strtotime($pieces1[0]); // use spaceship operator
}

// sort array based on the date

usort($array, "check");

$value_raw = array_column($array, 'value_raw'); // get array of values from column "value_raw"

print_r(implode(',',$value_raw));
```

Comment: thank you for the input it really helped me to come up with a solution

Comment: Yw glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
    $today= date('Y-m-d');
    $thirty_days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

then, in db query builder,

```
    $data = DB::table('your_table_name')
           ->where('datetime','>='$thirty_days_ago)
           ->where('datetime','<='$today)
           ->whereRaw('value_raw = (select max(`value_raw`) from your_table_name)')
           ->select('datetime','value_raw')
           ->groupBy('datetime')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire query if you are using mysql to group by date and get max value,

```
SELECT MAX(value_raw), DATE(mydate) DateOnly FROM a_table where mydate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY DateOnly;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this comment, it will be helpful for future reference. However I'm not using MySQL as of now, I'am using a json file via api

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys this is what i have come up with:

```
data: [
<?php
  for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++)
  {
      $date = date('n/j/Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime(date('n/d/Y'))));

      $filterBy     = $date;
      $new_array    = array_filter($my_array, function ($array) use ($filterBy) {
          $datetime = date("n/j/Y",changeFormat($array['datetime']));
          if ($datetime == $filterBy)
          {
            return $datetime;
          }
      });

      if (count($new_array) != 0)
      {
        $max_value = max(array_column($new_array, 'value_raw'));
        echo number_format($max_value, 0, '.', '').",";
      }
  }
?> ],
```